# Count colored cell on excel automatically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to count the number of cells based on colors, currently using a VBA code that already does it. But it doesnt update automatically and I will have to manually keep refreshing it. Any way to fix this?

Thank you!!

Current VBA code:

```
Function CountCellColor(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range)
Dim Color As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Color = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set rCell = CountRange
For Each rCell In CountRange
If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = Color Then
Total = Total + 1
End If
Next rCell
CountCellColor = Total
End Function
```

Comment: Colour is not data. Use numbers or text to flag your data. Then you can use conditional formatting based on hard data, and you can use the hard data for summing and counting in worksheet formulas.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back! I'm already able to count the cell based on colored cells, just that its not updating automatically

Comment: Yeah, that's because colour is not data!! Colouring a cell does not trigger any events, or recalc, because no data has changed.

Comment: Could you describe how the colors in `CountRange` are being changed?

Comment: You could make the function volatile. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile . Just add application.volatile at the top of the code